# How can I embed a Google Map in Streetview mode with an iframe?

Tags: html, google-maps, iframe, google-maps-api-3

When I pull up a Google Map, there is a little gear icon near the bottom-right that allows me to share. It includes finding an embeddable `<iframe>`. However, once I go into Streetview this gear icon disappears.

How can I embed the streetview version of the map?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you're in the Streeview mode, click on the "[link button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJawy.jpg)" next to the print button. You'll have an iframe and a link to customize and preview it.

Comment: I do not see anything like that on the map.

Comment: If you're using Google Maps [from the official website](https://maps.google.com/) you should have a panel on the left with this button.

Comment: The map is fullscreen, wit a small black box in the top-left corner with the address/info, scrollable thumbnails stacked on the bottom, and this little interface: http://screencast.com/t/KAW2HMNI2Gf7

Comment: You should copy the adress, find it on the Google Maps website and use the Streetview on it, it'll be far easier to get the iframe code like that.

Comment: Thanks, Zealot. I had to log out of Google to view it in the older Maps. The method you described was then accessible once again.

Answer (score 11):

It appears the problem is that the new google maps does not have a way to embed.

If you click on the [image: ?]  in the bottom right corner while NOT in pano / street view  mode you can revert to [classic maps](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3045828?hl=en)

Then you'll see  [image: the link]

from there you can select embed frame.

Comment: Thank you for this tip. Viewing the new Maps was indeed the issue.

Comment: no problem I was struggling with the same thing. 

could you do me a favor and accept / vote since you found it useful?

Answer (score 4):

Since Google changed in the past two years I'll post an answer that shows how to embed Street View with the new Maps.

- Enter in Street View Mode with the best view you want
- Click those "three dots" on the top left corner of the screen

  [image: Dots]
- Click "Share or Embed Image"

[image: Embed Image]

- Click on the tab "Embed Image" and copy/paste the code
  of the `iframe`

[image]

Comment: Thanks, any idea how to disable Scroll Zoom?

Answer (score 3):

its too simple .just go to link below https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-embed

copy the html+javascript code into your page and modify the div style (by default it goes full screen) having id= map-canvas

now go to the desired street view and copy the latitude,longitude in the url then replace in your code in initialize function latling(latitude,longitude) done!!!!  happy to post my first answer stack overflow has answered me so many times

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a more generic way, for example to display embedded streetview based on the regular google map link or coordinates. Here is my solution:

Extract coordinates from a regular link

```
export const getCoordinatesFromGoogleMapURL = (url: string) => {
  if (!url) {
    return undefined
  }
  const urlParts = url.split('/@')[1]?.split(',')

  if (!(urlParts && urlParts?.length > 1)) {
    return undefined
  }

  const gpsX = parseFloat(urlParts[0])
  const gpsY = parseFloat(urlParts[1])

  if (isNaN(gpsX) || isNaN(gpsY)) {
    return undefined
  }

  return [gpsX, gpsY] as [number, number]
}
```

Generate embed url from coordinates:

```
export const generateGoogleMapEmbedUrl = (coordinates: [number, number]) => {
  if (!coordinates) {
    return undefined
  }

  const baseUrl = "https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/streetview"
  const coordinatesString = `${String(coordinates[0])},${String(coordinates[1])}`
  const url = `${baseUrl}?key=${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY}&location=${coordinatesString}`

  return url
}
```

Finally we can put it together:

```
export function convertToEmbedURL(url: string): string {
  const coordinates = getCoordinatesFromGoogleMapURL(url)
  const embedUrl = generateGoogleMapEmbedUrl(coordinates)

  return embedUrl;
}
```

You can read the official docs to find out more about params etc: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/embedding-map#streetview_mode